# Is there a difference between pyplot Circle and patches Circle?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to check the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html), but I couldn't find matplotlib.Circle in it. I also checked matplotlib.patches.circle and couldn't see anything saying that matplotlib.Circle is a place holder of matplotlib.patches.circle.

Do they operate differently?

Thank you.

Edit: I forgot that plt is a very common abbreviation for matplotlib.pyplot rather than matplotlib itself, which resulted in this question.

Comment: I can't import `Circle` from `matplotlib`. Are you sure it does exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're referring to `matplotlib.pyplot.Circle` and [`matplotlib.patches.Circle`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html). A quick check:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.patches.Circle is matplotlib.pyplot.Circle
True
```

This means that both classes are the same object. This happens because `matplotlib.pyplot` imports `Circle` from `matplotlib.patches` ([source code at GitHub](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.5.1/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L76)):

```
# Line 76 at matplotlib/pyplot.py (tag "v3.5.1")
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon, Rectangle, Circle, Arrow
```

Comment: Thanks, my bad. Always importing ```matplotlib.pyplot as plt``` made me forget about pyplot altogether